# Como usar un archivo excel como una base de datos en visual studio usando csharp

Tags: c#, excel

quisiera saber como usar un archivo excel como una base de datos usando c sharp en visual studio. Esto aun no me lo enseñan pero me gustaría aprender para aplicarlo en mi trabajo de la universidad. Tengo una clase libro y una clase alumno que tiene una lista de libro. El libro tiene los atributos de Titulo, Autor, Código y  Área. Ahora me gustaría cargar los datos de un archivo excel que se ve así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí tendría 2 libros y quisiera añadir esos libros como dos objetos de la clase libro para poder disponer de ellos en el programa sin tener que crear libros, tan solo sacarlos del documento. Como podría ejecutarlo? 
Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo que dejes el código de lo que has intentado hasta ahora, para que sea más sencillo ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar `OleDb`

Por ejemplo;

**Select**

```
//Definis la ruta
String filename=@"D:\dem.xlsx";  
//Definis el connectionString
String connection=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filename+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\""; 
//Definis la Query 
String Command="Select * from [sheets$]";  
//Instancias un nuevo objeto de tipo OleDbConnection y abris la conexión con .Open();
OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(connection);  
con.Open();  
//Definisun Command pasándole tu query y el objeto de conexión
OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand(Command,con);  
//Por último creas un Adapter y se lo asignas a un DataTable
OleDbDataAdapter db=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);  
DataTable dt=new DataTable();  
db.Fill(dt);  
//Ahora ya tenes acceso a la información del documento excel, podes, por ejemplo, asignarla como DataSource de un dataGridView
dataGridView1.DataSource=dt;
```

**Insert**

```
//Definis la ruta
String filename=@"D:\dem.xlsx"; 
//Definis el connectionString
String connection=@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+filename+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;\"";   
//Definis tu Insert
String Command="insert into [sheets$](Codigo,Titulo, Autor, Area) values('valor_codigo','valor_titulo', 'valor_autor', valor_area)";
//Instancias un OleDbConnection y abris la conexión.
OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection(connection);  
con.Open();   
//Por último, creas el comando y lo ejecutas
OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand(Command,con);  
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando!

Comment: Ohhh esos valor_codigo, etc  vendrían hacer los atributos de la clase o las properties?

Comment: Vendrian a ser las variables que almacenan los valores que queres que se guarden en el archivo

Comment: Probare, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero puedo sugerir que uses Integration Services para hacer tareas programadas para que actualice tu BD pero si quieres hacer una rutina a traves de programación te sugiero este código:

```
string ExcelContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"; 
string Excel2010ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"; 
if (FileUpload1.HasFile) 
{ 
    //verifica el contenido del archivo 
    if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType==ExcelContentType || FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType==Excel2010ContentType) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            //Guarda la ruta del archivo 
            string path = string.Concat(Server.MapPath("~/TempFiles/"), FileUpload1.FileName); 
            //Guarda el archivo en un temporal 
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(path); 
            //ejemplo de la ruta del archivo  = @"C:\Users\Johnney\Desktop\ExcelData.xls"; 
            string excelConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path); 

            // se conecta a la base de datos obtiene la hoja del excel y selecciona el que quieras 
            using (OleDbConnection connection = 
                         new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString)) 
            { 
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand 
                        ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection); 

                connection.Open(); 

                // empieza a generar un datareader
                using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                { 

                    // tu conexion de base de datos 
                    string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=ExcelDB;Integrated Security=True"; 

                    // Copia la data a la base de datos 
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = 
                               new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString)) 
                    { 
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Employee"; 
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr); 
                        Label1.Text = "los datos fueron recibidos exitosamente"; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        catch (Exception ex) 
        { 
            Label1.Text = ex.Message; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Employee es a donde envio los datos verdad?

Comment: @DavidZaplana así es, esa es tu tabla a la que se redirrecciona. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pasa de OLE, o de las clases que te instala office (interop). Utiliza alguna de las tantas librerías que te permiten leer y escribir datos desde y hacia excel, sin quedar amarrado a necesitar que la máquina tenga instalado excel.

Un ejemplo de librería es LinqToExcel, la encuentras aquí: https://github.com/paulyoder/LinqToExcel te permite hacer busquedas de forma fácil y sobretodo con ayudas del compilador (strong typed).

Otro ejemplo es EPPlus, que la encuentras aquí: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus